# Sublime Text 3: change sidebar width

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible to change the default sidebar width in Sublime Text 3? I would like to increase the default width in order to show the entire folder and file names.

Comment: all you do is click on the border and drag...

Comment: @MattDMo Apologises for the duplicate. I found this post but assumed it to refer to sublime text 2 because of its tab title stating "sublimetext2". Indeed dragging the border works but this change is not persistent.

Comment: What do you mean by _is not persistent_?

Comment: @sergioFC On close and re-opening of Sublime Text 3, the sidebar width is restored to the default width.

Comment: For me is persistent on close and re-opening. I'm using sublime text 3 build 3083 on linux mint.

Comment: While it wasn't persistent for a specific folder, I opened a blank new window, displayed the sidebar and changed the width there. Now it remains persistent. Thanks for your help!